# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting this error:

> Exception occurs here in line db.SaveChanges(); 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll.Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

What is wrong with the code? Plz help me. Below is my Code.

Model class:

```cs
public class EmployeeDb : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("EmployeeTable");
    }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeAddress { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Controller class:

```cs
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Employee emp)
    {
        EmployeeDb dbobj = new EmployeeDb();
        dbobj.Employees.Add(emp);
        dbobj.SaveChanges();
        return View("Employee",emp);
    }
}
```

View :

```
@model EmployeeMgmt.Models.Employee

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Employee",FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()   

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Employee</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

What is causing this error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What's the EmployeeID field configured as in the database? Is it an autogenerated number?

Comment: Thank u, No i m manually entering on the view page.

Comment: It's very unusual to manually type in the entity ID field.  Is it possible you've typed in the same number twice?

Comment: @Neil,no first i made that Id field hidden, it was giving same error.

Comment: If the Id field is neither entered, or autogenerated, then `dbobj.Employees.Add(emp);` will try and add a new record, with the same Id as an existing one.

Comment: @Sushma My educated guess is that you are trying to add a new record where one exists with the same ID. That's what's causing it to fail. Please post the code for your `[Get] Create` method. You cannot just allow users to edit the ID field and then expect it to be a new value. If you are going to go this route, you should check to see if a record with that ID already exists and either reject the operation or update the record.

Comment: @Sushma Also, make sure to debug to see that you are actually getting an ID value on `Post` from model binding.

Comment: i m getting the problem from beginning, i.e  when table was empty with no records. At that time, i dint add employeeID field manually ,only i was just adding other fields manually, where i encountered same problem. So then i made the id field to add manually, but still problem persisted.

Comment: @JuanR ,i debugged, i m getting id value on Post, but employee Id is showing 0

Comment: @Sushma: That doesn't make a lot of sense. If you are getting the ID value on `POST`, how can employee id be `0`? Check the `emp` object right **before** the call to `dbobj.SaveChanges();`. What's the value `EmployeeID` at this point?

Answer (score 0):

@Sushma Your Id field must contain a unique number.   This is normally done by allowing the database to choose that number for you.  In some cases, it can be generated by the code, but that can be difficult in multi-user systems.   The easiest fix is to add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to the id field in your model.   You will also need to create a [migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) to update the database with this new setting.

```
public class Employee
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
  public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
  public string EmployeeAddress { get; set; }
  public string EmployeeEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how to create migration?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli